# Statelist drawable android:state_enabled not working in xml

Tags: android, statelistdrawable

I'm trying to add to my existing statelist drawable, a disabled state and it just doesn't work.

originally, I had this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/store_item_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/store_item_background"/>
</selector>
```

and it worked perfectly for selected and not selected.

now I wanted to add the android:state_enabled="false" like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/store_item_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/store_item_background" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/store_item_background_disabled"/>
</selector>
```

and it never switches to the disabled image.

any ideas?

EDIT

I added `setEnabled(false)` to the constructor of the view I'm setting this statelist drwable and now I see the disabled image, but once I set the view to enabled, it won't switch to disabled again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/store_item_background_selected" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/store_item_background" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/store_item_background_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 44):

Although this is a really old question, one should write a selector in this order:

1. disabled state first
2. pressed state second
3. normal state last

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
    <item android:drawable="@color/due_gray" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/whizdm_primary_dark_color" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/whizdm_primary_color" />
</selector>
```

Comment: switching the order instantly fixed my problem. where did you find this information?

Comment: I had this problem for a long time using this approach: 
        StateListDrawable res = new StateListDrawable();
        res.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, new ColorDrawable(color) );
        res.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(color)); 
        res.addState(new int[]{}, new ColorDrawable(color)); 

And this worked immediately. Thanks. wish it was documented somewhere...

Comment: Anytime bro. This should be documented!

Comment: ridiculus still works. Why is the ordner necessary ...